# mvn dependency:tree shows weird dependencies

Tags: maven

I have a project that uses `hadoop-mapreduce-client-core` as a dependency. When I try to run my project, I get the following error

```
Classpath contains multiple SLF4J bindings
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/server/tomcat-8.0.35/temp/3-ex/WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/server/tomcat-8.0.35/temp/3-ex/WEB-INF/lib/logback-classic-1.1.2.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
```

So I checked the dependencies in my project to check where is the `slf4j-log4j12` jar is coming from since it is not in the list of dependencies I added in.

`mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12`

This gave me the following output

```
[INFO] com.me.ex:exprj:jar:1.1.0
[INFO] \- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-mapreduce-client-core:jar:2.7.1:compile
[INFO]    \- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.7.10:compile
```

Now, I am using the `hadoop-mapreduce-client-core` as a dependency in my project, but the [pom](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/2.7.1/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.7.1.pom) for this jar does not mention `org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12` as a dependency. So I am now wondering why the maven dependency:tree shows `slf4j-log4j12` as a compile time dependency?

Comment: It comes from the parent POM of `hadoop-mapreduce-client-cor`', http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-mapreduce-client/2.7.1/hadoop-mapreduce-client-2.7.1.pom

Comment: Does the dependencies mentioned in the parent automatically get added to all child modules? I would expect that only the dependencies mentioned in the jar that I want would be added in.

Comment: Yes, "compile"-scoped artifacts propagate to dependent projects: http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope